# Setting setTimeOut in a react class base component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

Plaese I want to setTimeOut in my class base component. Trying different method but still it did not work. I want the setTimeout to call nextClick/onClickI after a specified second but, still don't understand how to go about it. Please help, if you have an idea. below is the component code...

```
class AbCarousel extends Component {
    state = {
        data: []
    }

    myRef = React.createRef();

    getData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('aboutdata.json');
        const data = await res.json();
        this.setState({data: data})
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }


 prevClick = () => {
     const slide = this.myRef.current;
     slide.scrollLeft -= slide.offsetWidth;
     if (slide.scrollLeft <= -0){
         slide.scrollLeft = slide.scrollWidth; 
     }
    };


 nextClick = () => {
        const slide = this.myRef.current;
     slide.scrollLeft += slide.offsetWidth;
     if (slide.scrollLeft >= (slide.scrollWidth - slide.offsetWidth)) {
         slide.scrollLeft = 0; 
     }
    };
 
    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        return (
                <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="app" ref={this.myRef}>
                    <AbCard data={data} />
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="prev" onClick={this.prevClick}>
                    <div><FaChevronLeft /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="next" onClick={this.nextClick}>
                    <div><FaChevronRight /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AbCarousel
```

Comment: It doesn't appear you call `setTimeout` in your code. Can you update your question to include the relevant code you are trying to use `setTimeout` in? What is the problem you are trying to solve with a timeout? When/where do you want a timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is just to update your `onClick` handler to take `setTimeout` as a callback like the following

`onClick={() => setTimeout(this.nextClick, numSeconds)`

or you can update the `nextClick` method directly and use a callback function within the `setTimeout` and wrap around the code you wish to delay the execution on:

```
 nextClick = () => {
   const slide = this.myRef.current;
     
   setTimeout(() => {
     slide.scrollLeft += slide.offsetWidth;
     if (slide.scrollLeft >= (slide.scrollWidth - slide.offsetWidth)) {
         slide.scrollLeft = 0; 
     }, numSeconds)
   }
```

Comment: If you do this you should save a ref and clear the timeout on unmount